# How to set Am/Pm?

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using date picker plugin for an android application. I got a plugin from link https://github.com/brodyspark/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/DatePicker. Can anyone tell me how to set meridian for time picker?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change last parameter in [TimePickerDialog's constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html#TimePickerDialog%28android.content.Context,%20android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) (which is named `is24HourView`) from `true` to `false`. It's line 101:

```
final TimePickerDialog timeDialog = new TimePickerDialog(currentCtx, timeSetListener, mHour,
      mMinutes, true);
```

should be

```
final TimePickerDialog timeDialog = new TimePickerDialog(currentCtx, timeSetListener, mHour,
      mMinutes, false);
```